# Change the last 20 lines of a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I change only last 20 lines and not the all the contents.

```
@echo off > newfile & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion
copy /Y E:\LOG.DIR LOG.DIR
set old=INACTIVE
set new=ACTIVE
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (LOG.DIR) do (
set str=%%a
echo %SOON
set str=!str:%old%=%new%! >> newfile echo !str!
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it out:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
copy /Y E:\LOG.DIR LOG.DIR
set "old=INACTIVE"
set "new=ACTIVE"
FOR /f %%a IN ('^<log.DIR find /v /c ""') DO SET /a length=%%a
SET /a length-=20
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
<log.DIR  (
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%length%) DO (
    SET "line="
    SET /p "line="
    ECHO(!line!
))>newfile
ENDLOCAL
for /f "skip=%length% delims=" %%a in (LOG.DIR) do (
    set "str=%%a"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "str=!str:%old%=%new%!"
    >>newfile ECHO(!str!
    endlocal
)
```

Get with `find` the number of rows, minus 20, put the result to `skip=` in the `for /f` loop.

Comment: @user2558845 yes, you are right. I forgot some debug code and made an edit, sorry for that.

Comment: @user2558845 is fixed now :)